# Ionic Pro Packaging IOS App errors

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-v1

Trying to build and package an iOS app in Ionic Pro - though am running into these errors:

[12:20:43]: Exit status of command 'cordova platform add ios --nofetch' was 1 instead of 0.

then as well

Running command: /Users/ionic/builds/project-1/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /Users/ionic/builds/project-1

Error: spawn EACCES

fastlane summary

|    | cordova platform add ios --nofetch

[12:20:43]: fastlane finished with errors

ERROR: Job failed: Process exited with: 1. Reason was:  ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved by `git add . --chmod=+x` command.

Then commit and push.

Answer (score 0):

cordova platform add ios --nofetch

this will install the latest version of ios platform and then if you are using inappbrowser then
run these commands:
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser